# html2Canvas background Stretched Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html2canvas

I'm using html2canvas for generating image of canvas with the background it work pretty fine with the firefox but in chrome the background is vertically stretched, I'm not sure what is the problem with it.

Here is my fiddle link

http://jsfiddle.net/vnL0jLmc/

code for it

```
html2canvas(document.getElementById('DBackgroundContainer'), {
            allowTaint: true,
            taintTest: false,
            onrendered: function(canvas) {
              document.body.appendChild(canvas);
            }
        })
```

Comment: This fixes a different type stretching problem... https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/725#issuecomment-392329119

Answer (score 0):

the problem is this:

```
background-size: 547px auto;
```

For some reason in chrome, html2canvasdoesn't like "547px auto" (or "547px" alone for that matter). Declare both background size parts and you'll see it works.

I'm submitting a bug report right now, hopefully it gets fixed, but for now you can get it working again.

Comment: the developer is super on top of it and already fixed it, so look for it in an upcoming release: https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/517#event-224915436